# Injecting another service into service for testing - Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-testing

I have two services, and one of them is dependent on another:

`UserService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService){}
  ...
}
```

`ApiService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(){}
  ...
}
```

So my problem is that I am struggling to inject the dependency, `ApiService` into my tests for the `UserService`. Here's what I have in the user service spec. (imports omitted):

```
describe('UserService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
      UserService,
      provide(ApiService, {useClass: MockApiService})
    ]);
  });

  it('Should ...', inject([UserService], (service: UserService) => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }));
})
```

The error that this throws is:

```
Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'UserService'(undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'UserService' is decorated with Injectable.
```

What I also tried was to add the `ApiService` in the `inject` inside the `it`, but the error stays the same, so:
`it('Should ..., inject([UserService, ApiService] ...))`

Angular 2 RC4 with TypeScript

Comment: Can you try to replace `beforeEach addProviders` part with `beforeEachProviders` . beforeEachProviders(() => [
      provide(ApiService, {useClass: MockApiService}),UserService
    ]);

Comment: `beforeEachProviders` is getting deprecated, however still is available in RC4, so i just tried it out. `beforeEachProviders(() => [UserService,provide(ApiService, {useClass: MockApiService})]);`, but the error still stays, i'm afraid